# Changing Font and Font Size in Header/Footer Without Deleting Content

Tags: excel, vba

I'm encountering an issue in VBA where Header and Footer content is deleted any time I attempt to change the font type and font size. This issue doesn't seem header/footer position specific and occurs on all center, right, and left headers/footers.

I've tried utilizing the record function to try and troubleshoot however, it is either only picking up the existing input or just clearing the contents. Most methods seem to set the header/footer from a known value, where I need it to be dynamic. The idea here being a tool that will set the header to Arial, Font size 10 no matter the existing header/footer contents.

I've also tried setting the header content to a variable or throwing it into a cell, but haven't had much luck with that route. My focus has been modifications/variants of Pagesetup, such as the below:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With Activesheet.PageSetup
     .LeftHeader = "&""Arial,Regular""&10"
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Anyone have any idea on what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell it to include the existing text:

```
Application.PrintCommunication = False
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
     .LeftHeader = "&""Arial,Regular""&10" & .LeftHeader
End With
Application.PrintCommunication = True
```

Comment: Amazing, thank you! I was close, but not quite there. Works perfectly.